# What is the easiest way to replicate the tags textbox that is used in the stackoverflow questions page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, tagging

i am building a asp.net-mvc website and i want to support tagging on each page.  I want to exactly replicate the inteface and UI that is used on stackoverflow (include both behavior and layout, css).

What is the easiest way to leverage this.  is there some jquery plugin that is used for something like this or is it homegrown?

Comment: ooo - i reckon you might get a reasonable response if you put an attempt (even in psuedo code) as to how you'd approach it. shows a bit more thought, rather than being misconstrued as hoping to get a complete code download for a one line question :-)

Comment: @jim - thanks for your feedback.  my point was that I didn't want to start building a solution from scratch if they happen to be using a jquery plugin that already exists that i can use. THAT was my question listed above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This jQuery plugin seems pretty close: <strike>http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin</strike>

**Update link**: https://github.com/drewwilson/AutoSuggest

Comment: It's funny I run into this question because I just found that yesterday and have plans on using it very soon.

Comment: i've got a use case for it coming up too, so will bookmark it. ooo, after all is said and done, i've given you a +1 as it guided me to this solution :)

Comment: Mike - i found a minor issue in the logic of the plugin. if you add/remove items, the intial item is NEVER removed from the .as-values list. open the jquery.autosuggest.js file and goto line 334 and change it to this: `values_input.val(values_input.val().replace(data[opts.selectedValuesProp] + ",", ""));`

Comment: @Mike C. - this plugin DOESN"T allow you to enter your own tags.  It just forces you to choose from the dropdown.  Am i missing something ??

Comment: @jim - how is it a contender . . it doesn't support adding your own tags . . it only allows you to choose from the dropdown.

Comment: ooo - sorry, my view on the plugin was based on being able to do an ajax request to populate your own tags (or, as per the example, add the tags as a json array). based on my tests, it's infinately extensible, to the degree that you can use it either locally or remotely. if there's a scenario that you're not able to overcome with this plugin, plz update - it's usually possible with a bit of sideways thinking... :0 i also saw an example on the page of adding a 'bespoke' tag via the dropdown, but this wasn't a scenario that i was too concerned by at the time of review. haven't checked ie6 yet.

Comment: ooo - hate the term, but with all due respect, you didn't specify the requirement to be able to add tags in your question, therefore you're only going to get suggestions that satisfy the criteria set out. I'd also add that referencing the way that SO does it, may not be clear to every user as you only get the ability to add tags when you hit a threshold (might be 3.5k, not sure) therefore, is invisible to a %age of your audience. i'm not b%tchin, just clarifying the criteria..

Comment: @jim - appreciate your feedback . .  still trying to find the "perfect" solution

Comment: no worries, i know how it can be!! good luck in the search, update when you find the best fit