# textboxlist for bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, textboxlist

I am looking for textboxlist implementation that uses bootstrap and jquery. I found one on web but it seems to require Mootools: 
https://github.com/guille/TextboxList

I am at a beginner level and not sure how much effort will it take to create a similar functionality on my own. If there are open-sourced libraries out there I would love to use them.

What I am trying to do is implement a `textbox` where users can start typing free form text and whenever a `space` is encountered it turns that into a `button` appearing embedded within the textbox with a close button. Essentially, each word will be it's own button. In appearance it will look something like the following minus the drop-down:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [jQuery autocomplete tagging plug-in like StackOverflow's input tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519107/jquery-autocomplete-tagging-plug-in-like-stackoverflows-input-tags)
[What is the easiest way to replicate the tags textbox that is used in the stackoverflow questions page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041171/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-replicate-the-tags-textbox-that-is-used-in-the-stacko)

Somone (Nishant) in the first list suggested this for bootstrap: http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will try some of them and let you know. When I searched I used the term 'textboxlist' thinking it's the standard name for this kind of widget. But it seems this thing goes by different names :-)